# How do I build 64-bit binaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit

ALL,

I have MSVC 2010 and currently working on the program in C++.

The current solution I'm building is for x86. Basically I'm just opening the solution inside an IDE and build it.

Now, what do I do if I need to build 64-bit binary. What to change inside solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN explains exactly, step by step, how to set the Visual Studio Solution for x64: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)